# Moving the $startOfLine pointer to the start of next line

Tags: php, string

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Justifying Lines of Text</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
<style>
pre {font-family: Courier, monospace;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Justifying Lines of Text</h1>

<?php

// The text to justify

$myText = <<<END_TEXT
But think not that this famous town has
only harpooneers, cannibals, and
bumpkins to show her visitors. Not at
all. Still New Bedford is a queer place.
Had it not been for us whalemen, that
tract of land would this day perhaps
have been in as howling condition as the
coast of Labrador.

END_TEXT;

$myText = str_replace( "\r\n", "\n", $myText );

$lineLength = 40; // The desired line length
$myTextJustified = "";
$numLines = substr_count( $myText, "\n" );
$startOfLine = 0;

// Move through each line in turn

for ( $i=0; $i < $numLines; $i++ ) {
  $originalLineLength = strpos( $myText, "\n", $startOfLine ) - $startOfLine;
  $justifiedLine = substr( $myText, $startOfLine, $originalLineLength );
  $justifiedLineLength = $originalLineLength;

  // Keep adding spaces between words until the desired
  // line length is reached

  while ( $i < $numLines - 1 && $justifiedLineLength < $lineLength ) {
    for ( $j=0; $j < $justifiedLineLength; $j++ ) {
      if ( $justifiedLineLength < $lineLength && $justifiedLine[$j] == " " ) {
        $justifiedLine = substr_replace( $justifiedLine, " ", $j, 0 );
        $justifiedLineLength++;
        $j++;
      }
    }
  }

  // Add the justified line to the string and move to the
  // start of the next line

  $myTextJustified .= "$justifiedLine\n";
  $startOfLine += $originalLineLength + 1;
```

The book's explanation of the above line is "The $startOfLine pointer is moved to the
start of the next line (adding **1** to the index to skip over the newline character).

My question is:

Shouldn't the new line character "\n" contains two characters? In order to skip it, shouldn't we add 2 to the variable $startOfLine instead of 1?

Let's see a simple example:

```
$myText = "Hello\nworld\n"

strpos ( $myText, "\n", 0); //Returns 5, which is also the length of the first line "Hello"
0+5+1; //Returns 6. It should be the index of the first character of the second line (w). But it's actually the index of the "n" right in front of it
strpos ( $myText, "\n", 6); //Returns 12
12-6   //Returns 6. This should be the length of the second line. But the second line actually contains 5 characters.
```

But the script won't work as it should if I change that 1 to 2. What's the problem?

```
}

?>

<h2>Original text:</h2>
<pre><?php echo $myText ?></pre>

<h2>Justified text:</h2>
<pre><?php echo $myTextJustified ?></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please note the difference between \n and /n the correct one is \n

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Now corrected.

Comment: I think I have figured out the problem. The line feed "\n" is counted as a single character by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) for justifying the text.

```
<?php
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");

echo $newtext;
?>
```

output:

```
The quick brown fox<br />
jumped over the lazy<br />
dog.
```

Comment: I haven't gone that far. I want to fully understand this script before moving on.